# How can I change an object's color through its color property?

Tags: objects, color, properties

Usually I change an object's color by assigning a material to it. But I also noticed that objects have a color property which can be modified in the user interface with

**Properties -> Object -> Display -> Object Color**

and in Python with

```py
bpy.data.objects['object_name'].color
```

However, neither of these methods seems to change the object's color in the 3D view or in a rendered image.

So, is there a way to use the color property to change an object's color? If not, what is the color property for?

Comment: You can set the Colour shown in Solid and Textured mode via the interface Material -> Settings -> Viewport Color. So the same property will be in the material via Python not the object. Not sure what the Object Color is, tool tip[ says used when in ObColor mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the *Display Mode* in *Solid View*, and pick *Object*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)